# AOSP 7.1.2 - Firefox (Fennec and IceCat) result with just a white screen

Tags: 7.1-nougat, aosp, application-error

I have installed a Custom ROM (AOSP 7.1.2) on a Samsung tablet. It is rooted, and also has gapps (pico).

Most everything works - except, when I installed both versions of Firefox for mobile - Fennec and IceCat (both via F-Droid), and the installation was successful (though neither of them asked for any permissions).

However, when I start either of them, they simply start as a white screen, and ... nothing happens (Fennec occasionally crashes after a few seconds of white screen, I have not seen IceCat crash so far, it just keeps at the white screen).

I captured a bit of `logcat` - first fennec is started, then icecat - it has been pasted here:

https://pastebin.com/ijGSr8X0

Would anyone have any idea as to why specifically these two Firefox apps start with nothing else but a white screen; and how to fix that?

(BTW, I use the same IceCat on an Android 4.x device; it works fine there.)

Comment: Posting the whole logcat is not useful at least truncate it and only post the log from the point on where you start one of the apps.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the concerned custom ROM in all likelihood is the cause of the problem. Firefox is actively supported for Android 5 and above. There is no reason it would suddenly go nuts for Android 7 alone. @sdaau, it is best if you ask the ROM maintainer to take a look at this and fix it. Probably a bug.

Comment: Sorry about the log being too verbose, I wasn't really sure what would have been most relevant. In any case, I did a bit of research, and the last Firefox Focus version that works on this device/OS for me is [8.0.19](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/focus-android/releases/download/v8.0.19/Focus-arm.apk), anything above that has the blank screen problem. For F-droid Fennec, I tried going all the way down to [68.6.0](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/mozilla/fennec-f-droid/fennec-f-droid-68-6-0-release/fennec-f-droid-68-6-0-android-apk-download/download/) which did not work, and I stopped there.

Comment: Btw, one more this: the Firefox Focus [8.0.19](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/focus-android/releases/download/v8.0.19/Focus-arm.apk) runs fine the first time, when it runs for the setup wizard, after that browsing works fine. But if you close it down and restart it, then it fails again (either crash, or blank screen). Workaround for this is: Settings / Apps / Firefox Focus / Storage / Clear Data & Clear Cache / (back) Force Stop ; then when starting it again, it will run the wizard again, and it will work.